# Messages issued by syslog not showing up in system logs

Tags: leopard, xcode

I'm having some trouble with `<syslog.h>` in 10.5. I'm writing a small fork based server for class and I want to use `syslog()` to print a bunch of debug info. However, I can't find any of the messages I issue via `syslog()` while using Console (I'm looking in both all messages & `system.log`).

Here is a code snippet of a plain C:

```
#include <syslog.h>
#include <stdarg.h>

int main (int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    openlog("Syslog Test", LOG_PID | LOG_NDELAY | LOG_CONS | LOG_PERROR, LOG_USER);
    setlogmask(LOG_UPTO(LOG_DEBUG));
    syslog(LOG_DEBUG, "%s", "Hello, World!");
    syslog(LOG_DEBUG, "%s", "And goodbye!");
    closelog();
    return 0;
}
```

And I don't see anything in "All Messages", "Console Messages" or `system.log`. Any advice?

Comment: Do you have syslog configured (/etc/syslog.conf) to accept debug entries?

Comment: It accepts debug entries from the kernal.

Comment: Ok, so what I ended up doing for the class was just to use syslog to dump everything to the terminals I was running my server and clients from, and then save the results.

I should have clarified that in the class, we were going strictly with POSIX APIs.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Despite what you pass to `setlogmask()`, in its default configuration, OS X will only write messages to the system log that have a priority of `LOG_NOTICE` or higher.

Any of the following will solve your problem...

1. Enable lower-priority logging in `/etc/syslog.conf` -- `kern.*` is not enough, as log messages from Xcode are not coming from the kernel
2. Change the priority of your messages from `LOG_DEBUG` to `LOG_NOTICE`
3. Simply use the built-in Xcode console -- the output will always appear there regardless of your `syslog.conf` settings

Here's what it looks like in the built-in Xcode 4 console:

[image: Xcode console]

Also, if you're developing exclusively for OS X, you might want to look into [ASL (Apple System Log)](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man3/asl.3.html), which was meant to replace `syslog()`.

Comment: I've heard of ASL, but I forgot to mention that for the purpose of the class I need to have my code be portable to Linux.

Comment: I've also been using `LOG_CONS` and `LOG_PERROR` to dump my syslogs to the terminal I am using (Xcode & Terminal).